# How to dynamically create monotonically increasing sequence in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, locking, sequence, counter

I have two domain entities: **employee** and **department**. DDL looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE department(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE employee(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  department_id integer,
  index_in_department integer
);
```

So, main field is **index_in_department**. It is unique monotonically increasing number per each department.

For example, I have 2 departments and 6 employees:

```
department - id == 1
department - id == 2

employee - id == 1, department_id == 1, index_in_department == 1
employee - id == 2, department_id == 1, index_in_department == 2
employee - id == 3, department_id == 1, index_in_department == 3
employee - id == 4, department_id == 2, index_in_department == 1
employee - id == 5, department_id == 2, index_in_department == 2
employee - id == 6, department_id == 2, index_in_department == 3
```

Is there any way to generate automatically **index_in_department** in PostgreSQL?

I cannot generate it on application level, because of concurrent inserts by multiple threads. I know, that I can use Database locks (e.g. advisory lock), but I want more easy and friendly solution.